# VBA переменная не увеличивается в цикле

Tags: vba

В окнах сообщений все время выводит 1. Но если из первой функции убрать первую строчку (строчку с делением), то все в порядке.

С чем это связано и что мне делать? Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
Function char_in_2(x As Integer)
    x = x \ 2
    char_in_2 = x
End Function

Function nayti(dlina As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0

    Do While char_in_2(i) <> dlina
        i = i + 1
        MsgBox i   
    Loop

    nayti = i
End Function

Sub Test1()
    MsgBox nayti(7)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В функцию Передается *Integer* - целое.
*x = x \ 2* - в переменную заносится число с отброшенной дробной частью. При i ={0;1} *char_in_2=0*.

Но это еще не все. Переменная х, передаваемая из функции *nayti*, меняет свое значение и в цикл возвращается 0 (ноль). Т.к. в цикле i никогда не поднимется выше 1, цикл становится бесконечным (7 никогда не появится).

' -----------------------

В *VBA* переменные в функцию передаются как *ByRef* или *ByVal*.

По умолчанию - *ByRef* - ссылка на  значение, которое может быть изменено в процессе работы функции.

*ByVal* - передача в функцию копии переменной.

Вывод: не применять одинаковые имена переменных (передаваемой и работающих в функции), если не предполагается изменение передаваемых данных. Иногда полезно явно указывать, что передается:

```
Function char_in_2(ByVal k As Integer)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! У меня еще один вопрос: это причуды VBA такие? Просто например если я в C++ передам в функцию значение переменной и эта функция уже внутри своего тела поменяет значение переданной переменной, то в теле, из которого я вызывал функцию, значение передаваемой переменной не поменяется.

Comment: Добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Не изменять переменную-аргумент внутри вызываемой функции.

```
Function char_in_2(x As Integer) as Integer
     Dim x2 as Integer
     x2 = x \ 2
     char_in_2 = x2
End Function
```

Comment: Об этом есть в предыдущем ответе (см. "Вывод:")